# How to give action to left navigation button using swift

Tags: ios, swift

Calling setupNavigationBar() function in viewdidload(), The left bar button has camera image and given action. Doesn't seems to work. Anything wrong I am doing?

```
func setupNavigationBar() {

    var backimage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Camera")

    self.navigationItem.title = "App_Name"
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backimage, style:.plain, target: nil, action: #selector(openCamera))
}

@objc func openCamera() {
    print("Clicked")
}
```

Comment: Set target to self.